# Javascript touch event: distinguishing finger vs. Apple Pencil

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari, touch-event

In Mobile Safari, is there any way to distinguish whether a touch event is generated by finger or Apple Pencil?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `TouchList` object of a touch event contains detailed information about the touch’s individual points. Among the many properties `touchType` is probably the most interesting for you as it contains either `"stylus"` (Apple Pencil) or `"direct"` (finger).

```
var body = document.querySelector('body');
body.addEventListener('touchstart', function(evt){
    // should be either "stylus" or "direct"
    console.log(evt.touches[0].touchType);
});
```

You should also have a look at the other properties of each individual Touch like `force` or `azimuthAngle` that can give you detailed information about the touch point’s current device(s).

> Please note that the Touch interface is only part of a [W3C working
> draft](https://w3c.github.io/touch-events/#touch-interface) and not official standard yet – however works in iOS 10 +
> Safari + Apple Pencil.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the touch force with:

```
e.touches[0].force;
```

But it works also for 3DTouch on iPhone 6s.

Only Apple Pencil events and touches events on iPhone 6s have .force

**EDIT**:

Nowdays there is `touchType` on iOs Safari:

`e.touches[0].touchType === 'direct' // this is a finger`

`e.touches[0].touchType === 'stylus' // this is an Apple Pencil`

Comment: This is hacky, but checking for `var isiPad = (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null);` and the existence of `force` on the touch event seems to be the only way to tell whether it's the Apple Pencil. Until Apple adds first class support for it in WKWebView/Safari, that is.