# How to draw or get pointer coordinates from HTML canvas when using Apple pencil?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, canvas, html5-canvas

I was working on getting mouse events like mouse down, up, move and drawing on an html canvas using my mouse and my Microsoft surface stylus. Now I want to try this with the ipad pro pencil, and I figure out that when the pencil in the canvas area, the canvas didn't recognize the pencil so I can't do any drawing or events. Is there any specific JavaScript library that I should use or any other solution available to use apple pencil with html canvas?

Comment: I never tried such device myself, but I guess it doesn't make an difference for the os if it's your finger or the pencil thing. Hence, did you try to listen for touch events ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apple Pencil works with `touch` events, not `mouse` events in HTML. You can set your canvas to listen for the touch events and then check its `touchType` for **stylus**. Then you can get the clientX and clientY from that particular touch to do the drawing.

```
document.getElementById('mycanvas').addEventListener('touchmove', function(event){
    for(var i = 0; i < event.touches.length; i++){
         if(event.touches[i].touchType === "stylus"){
             console.log("x coordinate: " + event.touches[i].clientX);
             console.log("y coordinate: " + event.touches[i].clientY);
         }
    }
});
```

See the [W3C draft spec](https://w3c.github.io/touch-events/#dom-touch-touchtype) for touch events for more specifics. Also, see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34986373/javascript-touch-event-distinguishing-finger-vs-apple-pencil) for getting Apple Pencil touch events.

If you are looking for a library that can allow you to easily move between the Apple Pencil and the Surface Pen you should look at [Pressure.js](https://pressurejs.com/). It is fantastic and very easy to use.